# Scraping tables in Python3 with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Trying to scrape a table on one page, grab every link in it, and then scrape a specific section of each link by adding "#Section" to the end.

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Magic Browser"})
con = urllib2.urlopen( req )
string = con.read().decode('utf-8')
print(string)
```

I'm not sure how to find a specific table, though - this prints a string but I don't know how to parse it, and json.loads(string) gives me an error

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Also, User_Agent is a workaround because I get a 403 error otherwise

Comment: Of course it does, `json.loads` is not an html parser. You've imported `BeautifulSoup`, use it.

Comment: if you got HTML string then use `BeautifulSoup` to parse and search elements. You have [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: I suggest starting by reading the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and perhaps a tutorial like [this one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-beautiful-soup-and-python-3).